# HTTPS endpoint of Azure event hub

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub

I am using service that can only send messages using webhook. The only thing I can set up in that webhook are HTTP endpoint, user name and password (you can see it on the screenshot below). I would like to send messages to my event hub, but I don't know how to find its HTTP endpoint. The only thing I could find was SAS Endpoint.

[image]

Comment: Azure Event Hub client sdk provide ways to connect to the Event Hub namespace via connection string and the name of the Event hub. There is no direct https endpoint to that specific Event Hub. You may need to write a function app which sends messages to the Event Hub, and in the above config screen provide your function app https url.

Answer (score 1):

Event Hubs offers a REST API that allows you to perform a subset of the  operations supported by its AMQP API.  Publishing basic events via REST is possible and would use the endpoint: `https://{servicebusNamespace}.servicebus.windows.net/{eventHubPath}/messages`.

The full set of documentation for the REST API can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/rest/api/eventhub/event-hubs-runtime-rest), and the specifics for sending events [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/rest/api/eventhub/send-event).

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand it correctly, but to use it I need to use SAS token as a authorisation method. The only parameters that I can use for authorisation are User name and password. Should I insert SAS token to the HTTP endpoint?

Comment: The REST endpoints do not support basic authentication; if you're not able to add custom headers so that you can pass the needed token, then the suggestion that Aanand made for standing up your own HTTP endpoint and then forwarding the event is going to be your best bet.

Comment: I have discovered that it is possible to use token authorisation in this webhook. However I have tried both primary and secondary key from SAS Policy and it didn't work. Do you know how I can pass sas token in http message?

Comment: They're passed via the standard HTTP header mechanism; the first link that I included above has authorization details.